# Laravel 5.5 DataTables Yajra Ajax Crud

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.5

I am adding and deleting with ajax but I am having trouble updating.

My Route File **wep.php**

```
Route::get('room-list', 'RoomController@list');
Route::resource('room', 'RoomController', [
        'except' => ['create']
    ]);
Route::get('api/room', 'RoomController@apiRoom')->name('api.room');
```

My view file **room-list.blade.php**

```
DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{url('assets/images')}}/favicon.png">
    <title>Room Insert, Update, Delete</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{{url('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{{url('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- You can change the theme colors from here -->
    <link href="{{url('css/colors/blue.css')}}" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
     {{-- dataTables --}}

    <link href="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body class="fix-header card-no-border">

    <div id="main-wrapper">

        @include('theme.sidebar')

        <div class="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

<div class="col-12">
    <div class="row page-titles">
            <div class="col-md-10">
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button onclick="addForm()" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-form"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Room</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Room List</h4>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle"></h6>
                                <div class="table-responsive m-t-40">
@if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{!! Session::get('success') !!}</p>
    </div>
@endif
@if (Session::has('deleted'))
    <div class="alert alert-warm">
            <p>{!! Session::get('deleted') !!}</p>
    </div>
@endif
@if (Session::has('edit'))
    <div class="alert alert-edit">
            <p>{!! Session::get('edit') !!}</p>
    </div>
@endif
    <table id="room-table" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Room ID</th>
                <th>Hotel ID</th>
                <th>Room Name</th>
                <th>Bonus Sum</th>
                <th>Settings</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach($rooms as $room)
            <tr>
                <td>{!! $room->room_id !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $room->hotel_id !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $room->room_name !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $room->bonus_sum !!}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

           @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 @include('room.room-form')
            </div>

            <footer class="footer">
                © 2017 
            </footer>

        </div>

    </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="{{ asset ('assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset ('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset ('assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset ('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url ('js/jquery.slimscroll.js') }}"></script>
    <!--Menu sidebar -->
    <script src="{{ url ('js/sidebarmenu.js')}}"></script>
    <!--stickey kit -->
    <script src="{{ url ('assets/plugins/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url ('assets/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url ('js/custom.min.js') }}"></script>
    {{-- dataTables --}}
    <script src="{{ asset ('assets/dataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>



--}}
<script type="text/javascript">


    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

      var table = $('#room-table').DataTable({
                      processing: true,
                      serverSide: true,
                      ajax: "{{ route('api.room') }}",
                      columns: [
                        {data: 'room_id', name: 'room_id'},
                        {data: 'hotel_id', name: 'hotel_id'},
                        {data: 'room_name', name: 'room_name'},
                        {data: 'bonus_sum', name: 'bonus_sum'},
                        {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
                      ]
                    });
      function addForm() {
        save_method = "add";
        $('input[name=_method]').val('POST');
        $('#modal-form').modal('show');
        $('#modal-form form')[0].reset();
        $('.modal-title').text('Add Room');
      }

function editForm(id) {
        save_method = 'edit';
        $('input[name=_method]').val('PATCH');
        $('#modal-form form')[0].reset();
        $.ajax({
          url: "{{ url('room') }}" + '/' + id + "/edit",
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data) {
            $('#modal-form').modal('show');
            $('.modal-title').text('Edit Contact');
            $('#room_id').val(data.room_id);
            $('#hotel_id').val(data.hotel_id);
            $('#room_name').val(data.room_name);
            $('#bonus_sum').val(data.bonus_sum);
          },
          error : function() {
              alert("Nothing Data");
          }
        });
      }

      function deleteData(id){
            var popup = confirm("Are you sure for delete this data ?");
            var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            if (popup == true ){
                $.ajax({
                    url : "{{ url('room') }}" + '/' + id,
                    type : "POST",
                    data : {'_method' : 'DELETE', '_token' : csrf_token},
                    success : function(data) {
                        table.ajax.reload();
                    },
                    error : function () {
                        alert("Oops! Something Wrong!");
                    }
                })
            }
        }
      $(function(){
            $('#modal-form form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
                if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()){
                    var id = $('#id').val();
                    if (save_method == 'add') url = "{{ url('room') }}";
                    else url = "{{ url('room') . '/' }}" + id;

                    $.ajax({
                        url : url,
                        type : "POST",
                        data : $('#modal-form form').serialize(),
                        success : function($data) {
                            $('#modal-form').modal('hide');
                            table.ajax.reload();
                        },
                        error : function(){
                            alert('Oops! Something Error!');
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The following codes are included in the room-list.blade.php file with the include function of the form file

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" action="{{ route ('room.store') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('POST') }}
        <input type="hidden" name="room_id" id="room_id">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true"> &times; </span>
          </button>
          <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

           <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Hotel</label>
              <select id="hotel_id" name="hotel_id" class="select2 form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">
                    <option selected>Hotel Name...</option>

                </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Room Name</label>
             <input type="text" id="room_name" name="room_name" class="form-control">
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Bonus Sum</label>
               <input type="text" id="bonus_sum" name="bonus_sum" class="form-control">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button id="tamamla" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-save">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Controller File RoomController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Room;
use DataTables;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RoomController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index() {

    }

    public function list() {
        $rooms = Room::all();
        return view('room.room-list', compact('rooms'));
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create() {

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $data = [
            'hotel_id'  => $request['hotel_id'],
            'room_name' => $request['room_name'],
            'bonus_sum' => $request['bonus_sum']
        ];
        Room::create($data);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Kayıt başarılı bir şekilde eklendi!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id) {
        $data = Room::find($id);
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $room            = new \App\Room;
        $data            = $room->findOrFail($id);
        $data->hotel_id  = $request['hotel_id'];
        $data->room_name = $request['room_name'];
        $data->bonus_sum = $request['bonus_sum'];
        $data->update();
        return redirect()->back()->with('edit', 'Kayıt başarılı şekilde düzenlendi!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id) {
        $rooms = Room::find($id);
        $rooms->delete();
        return redirect()->back()->with('deleted', 'Kayıt başarılı şekilde silindi!');
    }

    public function apiRoom() {
        $rooms = Room::all();
        return Datatables::of($rooms)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($rooms) {
                return '<a onclick="editForm('.$rooms->room_id.')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil text-inverse m-r-10"></i> </a>'.
                '<a onclick="deleteData('.$rooms->room_id.')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Close"> <i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i> </a>';

            })->make(true);

    }
}
```

I think the problem is ajax related.

```
action="{{ route ('room.store') }}"
```

if I remove the action tag inside the form it does not work. If it remains this way the update does not work.

How can I run both update and add-on seamlessly in one form.

Best Regards

Comment: Consider adding only meaningful parts of your application, otherwise it looks cluttered and hard to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. No form action required with js file.

You can access this JavaScript file from this link [Validator.JS for Bootsrap 3](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

**Form code**

```
      <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator">
        {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('POST') }}
```

No action="" form tag

So you can add and update with one form

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you recreate always the list in the controller but you doesn't replace the old list in the page dom.

From your controller:

```
public function list() {
    $rooms = Room::all();
    return view('room.room-list', compact('rooms'));
}
```

you obtain the entire list and put it in response at the ajax call.

I think you must get the response from the javascript side and replace it in the page.
You can obtain that if you put the entire block of 'room-list' inside a div and replace the content of this div with javascript using the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

@Alviero thank your answer

New route code **web.php**

```
Route::get('room-list', function () {
        return view('room.room-list');
    });
Route::resource('room', 'RoomController', [
        'except' => ['create']
    ]);
Route::get('api/room', 'RoomController@apiRoom')->name('api.room');
```

And then new view file **room-list.blade.php**

```
<table id="room-table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="30">Room ID</th>
            <th>Hotel ID</th>
            <th>Room Name</th>
            <th>Bonus Sum</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

There are no problem route (api.room) works correctly.

But I give same error

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

file path vendor/symfony/routing/RouteCollection.php line 255

If I add form action tag **action="{{ route ('room.store') }}"**

It works. But this time the update is not working and it gives the same error.

Thank you again.